# How to make 18 separate scatterplots for 18 different columns from the same pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, subplot, scatter

How can I make three small scatterplots given the info below:

- A pandas dataframe `(df)` with in total 50 columns:

`df.columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", (...)]`

- A list with 18 column names for which I want to make three separate scatterplots:

`selection = ["A", "B", "C", (...)]`

- A point with a `value > 5.0` should be colored `blue`, points with a value `<= 5.0` should be colored `red`.

I tried the following code, but that did not work, any tips?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 5)
for column in selection:
    if column in df.columns:
    ax.scatter(df[column], if df[column][value > 5.0]: color = 'r', if df[column][value <= 5.0]: color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you will need to make a list of the values that are greater than 5 and another list for <= 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a quick function to convert values to colors. Also, you need to pass to arrays into each scatterplot where you pass just one.

```
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def colorUp(x):
    return 'b' if x <=5.0 else 'r'

# Each scatterplot requires two arrays. You are only passing one;
# I am assuming that this would be the second array passed into
# each '.scatter' call
second_array = np.arange(df.shape[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 5)
for i, column in enumerate(selection):
    if column in df.columns:
        ax[i % 4, i / 4].scatter(df[column], second_array, c = colorUp(df[column]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it, but keep getting `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'scatter'`.